# C++ Template gives unresolved function type

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make a template that compares the second item of pairs:

```
template <class T>
bool sortPairKey2(T u,  T v) { return u.second < v.second;}
```

this way if I have pairs of pairs, I can still use the function.

But when I use it in the sort method (from ) I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     sort(sums.begin(), sums.end(), sortPairKey2<iipair,iipair>);
                                                               ^
stp2mzn.cpp:409:63: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from stp2mzn.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5447:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
     sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5447:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
stp2mzn.cpp:409:63: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
     sort(sums.begin(), sums.end(), sortPairKey2<iipair,iipair>);
                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from stp2mzn.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:5: note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
     sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
stp2mzn.cpp:409:63: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Compare’
     sort(sums.begin(), sums.end(), sortPairKey2<iipair,iipair>);
```

where `typedef  pair<int,int> iipair`.

the function worked fine when instead of `T` I had `pair<int,int>`. I dont see what its problem is.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use lambda expression?

Comment: If you have made a regular function into a template function it can also be due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595015/c-class-template-undefined-reference-to-function/26816994#26816994

Comment: Even though you've already received two answers I believe to be correct, it would have been nice if you had posted the full code, i.e. including the *call* to the `std::sort` function, not just the functor itself.

Comment: @xuhdev: I dont use C++11 (my code is part of a bigger project and it seems like no one uses c++11 in it, I don't want to make stuff complicated in terms of linkage etc lol)

Comment: @Volodya thanks for that. Wasn't that, but its good to know!

Comment: @ChristianHackl well, the call is in the error message printed by g++....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try  `sortPairKey2<iipair>` instead of  `sortPairKey2<iipair,iipair>`

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

1. you should to pass the parameter by const reference
2. don't write `sortPairKey2<iipair, iipair>`, either get rid of the template specification completely (your compiler should figure it out), or just write `sortPairKey2<iipair>`

Comment: Agreed on your second point, but why the first? Should templates always be a const reference? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference